# Is there a page that lists bookmarked/favorited questions?

Tags: support, bookmarks

I was wondering if the Stack Overflow developers had created a bookmark page where all of my favourited questions will be displayed.

This page should also have a quick way to search its contents. I think that would be helpful to everyone.

Comment: I'm voting to migrate this to [Meta], because it's asking *about* Stack Overflow, although to be honest, I'm not 100% sure what this is even asking.  Are you talking about Favorites?

Comment: i can't understand your question

Comment: IMHO it's asking about if there's a page where you can see all the questions an user has starred and search through them

Comment: just updated my question, probably now it makes sense!

Comment: You can't search through them, but your favorite are on the Favorite tab:  http://stackoverflow.com/users/540495/isaiyavan-babu-karan?tab=favorites

Answer (score 0):

You can see all your favorite question/answers at that URL : https://stackoverflow.com/users/540495/isaiyavan-babu-karan?tab=favorites

You can also write in search:

> ```
> infavorites:mine
> ```

to search words in your favorites

Answer (score 0):

If you visit your profile you can see all your favorites in the *favorites* tab.

And you can search your favorites adding the search term

```
infavorites:mine
```

to the search box at the top.